# python propery: list-like object

Tags: python, properties

I'm trying to create an object with properties acting like a list. Here is what I mean.

```
class Unit:

    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

class Bundle:

    def __init__(self, N=3):
        self.units = [ Unit() for i in range(N) ]

    def getvals(self):
        return [ unit.val for unit in self.units ]

    def setvals(self, vals):
        for i, val in enumerate(vals):
            self.units[i].val = val

    vals = property(getvals, setvals)
```

Now, this object doesn't behave as expected.

```
>>> b = Bundle()
>>> b.setvals([1,2,3])
>>> print b.vals, b.getvals()
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
>>> b.vals = [4,5,6]
>>> print b.vals, b.getvals()
[4, 5, 6] [1, 2, 3]
```

So the statements "b.vals = x" and "b.setvals(x)" are not equivalent. Can you tell my why, and how to make it behave properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 2, `property` only works correctly for *new style* objects; your `Bundle` class *must* inherit from `object`:

```
class Bundle(object):
    ...
```

Once you make that correction, the property works as expected:

```
>>> b.vals = [4,5,6]
>>> b.vals
[4, 5, 6]
>>> b.getvals()
[4, 5, 6]
>>> [unit.val for unit in b.units]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete Martijn Pieters [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13660372/289011), which is probably the answer you wanted, I can't help showing a bit very fancy things you can do in Python and that got me very surprised when I found them out. I thought you may find them useful, or give you some ideas for the future.

### 1. Python `list` is an object, so you can extend your class from `list`

That will make your "Bundle" object to inherit all the methods from the built-in `list` object, and allow you to add new methods to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Unit(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.val = 0
  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s %s val=%s" % (type(self), hex(id(self)), self.val)

class Bundle(list):
  def __init__(self, N=3):
    super(Bundle, self).__init__()
    self.extend([ Unit() for i in range(N) ])
  @property
  def vals(self):
    return [ unit.val for unit in self]
  @vals.setter
  def vals(self, vals):
    vals = vals[0:min(len(self), len(vals))] # if len(vals) > len(self), self[i] would break
    for i, val in enumerate(vals):
      self[i].val = val

if __name__ == "__main__":
  bundle = Bundle()  
  print "Bundle: %s" % bundle
  newUnit = Unit()
  bundle.append(newUnit)
  print "Bundle: %s" % bundle
  bundle.vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  print "Bundle (reassigned): %s" % bundle
```

Please note that I changed a bit the property definition, to make them decorators, but the underlying idea remains the same.

### 2. You can overwrite certain built-in methods and have an object that is not a `list` behaving as a `list`:

Please be aware that this code is exclusively for sample purposes. It has a horrible design, a horrible OOP usage, its behavior would be extremely confusing for everybody (even for Guido van Rossum... well, maybe not for him, but I'm sure he'd cry if he saw it in a real program) It's a piece of... of... bad code, but I think it can help to understand what can you do overwriting built-in methods. Also, it lacks a lot of methods to be overwritten for the `Bundle` class behave as a real `list` object but I got kinda tired **:-)** Check [Emulating container types](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) and the next point, [Additional methods for emulation of sequence types](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#additional-methods-for-emulation-of-sequence-types) of the Python documentation for a complete reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Unit(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.val = 0
  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s %s val=%s" % (type(self), hex(id(self)), self.val)

class OtherUnit(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.whatever = "hello"
  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s %s whatever=%s" % (type(self), hex(id(self)), self.whatever)    

class Bundle(object):
  def __init__(self, N=3):
    self.units = [ Unit() for i in range(N) ]
    self.otherUnits = [ OtherUnit() for i in range(N) ]
  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.units + self.otherUnits)
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.units) + len(self.otherUnits)
  def __iter__(self):
    for item in (self.units + self.otherUnits):
      yield item
  def __contains__(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, Unit):
      return value in self.units
    elif isinstance(value, OtherUnit):
      return value in self.otherUnits
    elif isinstance(value, int):
      return value in [unit.val for unit in self.units]
    elif isinstance(value, str):
      return value in [otherUnit.whatever for otherUnit in self.otherUnits]
    else:
      return False
  def __getitem__(self, index):
    assert index >= 0, "Can't accept negative indexes (%s)" % indexes
    if index < len(self.units):
      return self.units[index]
    else:
      return self.otherUnits[index - len(self.units)] #Will raise index error if too big

  def append(self, thing):
    if isinstance(thing, Unit):
      self.units.append(thing)
    elif isinstance(thing, OtherUnit):
      self.otherUnits.append(thing)
    else:
      raise TypeError("Can't accept %s" % type(thing))

  @property
  def vals(self):
    return [ unit.val for unit in self.units] + [ otherUnit.whatever for otherUnit in self.otherUnits ]
  @vals.setter
  def vals(self, vals):
    insertionPointUnits = 0
    insertionPointOtherUnits = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(vals):
      if isinstance(val, int):  
    self.units[insertionPointUnits].val = val
    insertionPointUnits += 1
      elif isinstance(val, str):
    self.otherUnits[insertionPointOtherUnits].whatever = val
    insertionPointOtherUnits += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
  bundle = Bundle()  
  print "Bundle: %s" % bundle
  newUnit = Unit()
  bundle.append(newUnit)
  print "Bundle: %s" % bundle
  bundle.vals = [1, 2, "bye", 3, "how are you", 4, "doing ok"]
  print "Bundle (reassigned): %s" % bundle
  print "Bundle has %s items" % len(bundle) #Thanks to overwritting __len__
  for i, item in enumerate(bundle):
    print "bundle[%s]: %s" % (i, item) #Thanks to overwritting __iter__
  print "Does 'bundle' contain 'bye'?: %s" % ('bye'in bundle) #Thanks to overwritting __contains__
  print "Does 'bundle' contain 5?: %s" % (5 in bundle) #Thanks to overwritting __contains__
  print "Item 1 (should be Unit with val '2': %s" % bundle[1] #Thanks to overwritting __getitem__
  print "Item 5 (should be OtherUnit with val 'how are you' (4 Units + 1 OtherUnit... then ours!): %s" % bundle[5] #Thanks to overwritting __getitem__
  try:
    print "Item 9 (should raise IndexError): %s" % bundle[9]
  except IndexError, ie:
    print "Wooops: %s" % ie
```

Hope this helped a bit. Have fun with Python!